# Summernote: set focus after initialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, summernote

[Summernote](http://hackerwins.github.io/summernote/) gives you the option of giving focus to the editor when you create it, passing this options:

```
$('#summernote').summernote({
     focus: true
});
```

But after initialization, it seems you can't give focus to the textarea by clicking a button or similar. I've tried several ways, without success.

Anyone did that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
$('.summernote').summernote('focus')
```

ps. i want to find an angular way out .. and it works

Comment: doesn't look like an answer. Consider deleting 'cause it may ran into downvote-fall.

Answer (score 4):

After coming back to this problem and trying a lot of solutions, I came to one that works:

`$('.note-editable').trigger('focus');`

Triggering the event through jQuery works, but using the `focus()` function doesn't.

Comment: Did you find out why?

Comment: I have no idea. jQuery's doc says `.focus()` is just a shortcut for this syntax, so I don't really know if there's a difference.

Comment: What if someone want to do reverse, as in summernote 0.8.8 at the moment is getting focus on form init. I don't want this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                        $.fn.extend({
                            placeCursorAtEnd: function () {
                                // Places the cursor at the end of a contenteditable container (should also work for textarea / input)
                                if (this.length === 0) {
                                    throw new Error("Cannot manipulate an element if there is no element!");
                                }
                                var el = this[0];
                                var range = document.createRange();
                                var sel = window.getSelection();
                                var childLength = el.childNodes.length;
                                if (childLength > 0) {
                                    var lastNode = el.childNodes[childLength - 1];
                                    var lastNodeChildren = lastNode.childNodes.length;
                                    range.setStart(lastNode, lastNodeChildren);
                                    range.collapse(true);
                                    sel.removeAllRanges();
                                    sel.addRange(range);
                                }
                                return this;
                            }
                        });
                    });
```

then：

```
$('.note-editable').click(function(){
                                  //$('#summernote').summernote('focus');
                                  $(this).placeCursorAtEnd();
                                });
```

①focus on click or tap
②focus at the end of content

it works on mobile device too

Answer (score 0):

please refer [codepen](https://codepen.io/ondrejsvestka/pen/PROgzQ)
for this problem

> /* Summernote Validation */

```
$(function () {
    var summernoteForm = $('.form-validate-summernote');
    var summernoteElement = $('.summernote');

    var summernoteValidator = summernoteForm.validate({
        errorElement: "div",
        errorClass: 'is-invalid',
        validClass: 'is-valid',
        ignore: ':hidden:not(.summernote),.note-editable.card-block',
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            // Add the `help-block` class to the error element
            error.addClass("invalid-feedback");
            console.log(element);
            if (element.prop("type") === "checkbox") {
                error.insertAfter(element.siblings("label"));
            } else if (element.hasClass("summernote")) {
                error.insertAfter(element.siblings(".note-editor"));
            } else {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            }
        }
    });

    summernoteElement.summernote({
        height: 300,
        callbacks: {
            onChange: function (contents, $editable) {
                // Note that at this point, the value of the `textarea` is not the same as the one
                // you entered into the summernote editor, so you have to set it yourself to make
                // the validation consistent and in sync with the value.
                summernoteElement.val(summernoteElement.summernote('isEmpty') ? "" : contents);

                // You should re-validate your element after change, because the plugin will have
                // no way to know that the value of your `textarea` has been changed if the change
                // was done programmatically.
                summernoteValidator.element(summernoteElement);
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for `Summernote v0.8.18`:

```js
$(`div.note-editing-area div.note-editable`).focus();
```

Answer (score -2):

You can set the focus by putting the focus on the [editable div](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable) used by Summernote:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".note-editable").focus();
```

or using JQuery

```
$('#summernote').find('.note-editable').focus();
```

Comment: didn't work. at least on chrome. I can find the div but the focus don't work :(

Comment: maybe try to set the focus with a little timeout: `setTimeout(function() { $('#summernote').find('.note-editable').focus(); }, 200);`?

Answer (score -3):

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>  Skills</label>
        <span ng-messages="EditForm.Skills.$error" ng-if="EditForm.Skills.$dirty || isEditFormSubmitted ">
            <span class="text-danger" ng-message="required" ng-bind="error msg"></span>
        </span>
        <text-angular id="Skills" name="Skills" ng-model="EditVacancyModel.Skills" ta-toolbar="[['bold','underline','italics','ul','ol']]"ng-required="true"></text-angular>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: OP specified jquery. Also no explanation. -1